# How to add users in Active Directory with specific fields via a GUI

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation, active-directory

I want a way to add users to Active Directory using a GUI. Ideally I want to use PowerShell because I don't want to have to install additional software, and I'll be running it on a Windows machine. Ideally I'd have a form that the user would input the info in and it would be sent to Active Directory. I'd also be OK with building a web server, for example using JavaScript on the front end and Node/PHP on the backend. This seems like overkill and not a viable option at all, however I have more web development experience than PowerShell experience so I wouldn't be opposed to this method if there's a possibility, and the advantage of it is that I'd have a site I'd be able to access instead of an application. What language would be best for this task, and are there existing examples I could base my code off of to be able to accomplish this task? I've seen GUI examples [using XAML and PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/platformspfe/2014/01/20/integrating-xaml-into-powershell/) and also [using Visual Studio to create one](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/), but I'm not sure what the best method is.

Comment: XAML is the way to go for creating a GUI. Using Visual Studio is just an easier way to layout and generate the XAML code. Since PowerShell makes it easy to interact with Active Directory through the ActiveDirectory PS module, it would be much easier to have the GUI in XAML that then creates the user. Interacting with the web JavaScritp etc. would require much more development and permission settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend allowing a user to input their own into and sending it straight to active directory. Of course this would depend on what information you require the user to fill in and the amount of total freedom you want to offer them when creating your form.

I would recommend using WPF. What I currently do is use Visual Studios to design the GUI (being able to see the form without running the powershell script is great and having it break instantly on errors lets me find the problems instantly). Then you can copy the XML code into a powershell script and manipulate/read the fields from there.

As a quick example of the GUI in powershell (not guaranteed to work)

```
[xml]$form = @"
<Window
    Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="Button" Grid.Column="0">Test</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$XMLreader = New-object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form
$XMLForm = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::load($XMLreader)
$button= $XMLForm.FindName("Button")

$Button.add_Click({...code to execute on click...})

$XMLForm.ShowDialog()
```

Everything in the `$Form` variable is copied in from a Visual Studio WPF project. You can then assign scripts and code to be executed when certain actions are performed as sort of shown by `$Button.add_Click({})`

Otherwise you could also use some good old fashion Windows Forms to create a simple Gui, but I haven't used that in a while so I have no example code.